# Alignment issue for already received badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, design

Noticed an alignment issue when the badge description goes in more than 1 line.
the green tick mark is misaligned.

[Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus?userid=2345913)

> [image]

[Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer?userid=2345913)

> [image]

---

This doesn't affects for those with 1 liner description

[Sample 3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=2345913)

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build:

rev 2014.5.19.1611,  meta rev 2014.5.19.2253

Thanks for letting us know.